# Android - How to catch data from an other app

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

`Android 2.3` application running on a `Pidioin Device` that has a `barcode laser scanner`.

When it is triggered the device writes to logs:

```
SDGService(1450): Got Trigger On for 1dbarcode
SDGService(1450): Got Trigger Off for 1dbarcode
```

Is there a way to listen for the `SDGService`, and trigger an event for example `focus` on a `TextEdit`?

Is there a way to get the received data string?

Comment: Do the software publish any kind of API or intent documentatiom?

Answer (score 0):

Use this android logcat listener as described here :

http://itoobi.de/?page_id=310